# Flask response to a range request

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to create a response to a range request in Flask. There's not much info on how to do it, from what could be inferred from the docs, it's done like this:

```
return send_file('../video.mp4', mimetype='video/mp4', conditional=True)
```

But the browser doesn't cache the response. If I reload the page, it downloads the parts again.

I also get these errors all the time:

```
    self.wfile.write(data)
IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Writing here the solution that if finally found by trial and error: you have to manually delete the 'Expires' header, and leave only 'Cache-control'. Somehow having both those headers doesn't work, and Chrome would not cache the videos properly. Without 'Expires' header everything is cached ok.